# Why is the formula for the sum of infinite terms of a geometric progression only defined for $r < 1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The formula for the  the sum of infinite terms of a geometric progression  is $S_{\infty} = \dfrac{a}{1 - r}$, where $r < 1$. Why is this only defined for $r < 1$? My teacher doesn't know why.

Comment: What happens when you try to sum a geometric progression for which $r \ge 1$? For example for $r=2$, $a=1$: $1+2+4+8+16+.....$.

Answer (score 0):

Unless $a=0$ (meaning every term is 0), if $r \geq 1$ the terms in the series will grow larger and larger (towards ininity), and so the sum will be **infinite**.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $r\geq 1$. Then $\{r^n\}_{n\in\mathbf N}$ is *not* a null sequence. By the nth-term test for divergence the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n$$
can *not* converge.

Answer (score 0):

If $r> 1$, then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to +\infty} r^n=+\infty$. Since 
$$\forall n\in\Bbb N, \sum_{k=0}^n r^k= \frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$$
we deduce that 
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n r^k=+\infty$$
hence the formula is not correct.

If $r=1$, then 
$$\forall n\in\Bbb N, \sum_{k=0}^n r^k= \sum_{k=0}^n 1= n+1$$
which again tends to $+\infty$.